# mySQL: group elements by time

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a list of entries with a `user_id`, `track_id` and `created_at` fields.

Is it possible to group elements by user_id and track_id but only those which are inside a 30min window?

For example

```
| user_id    | track_id    | created_at   |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |        5    |     00:00    |
| 1          |        5    |     00:05    |
| 1          |        5    |     00:07    |
| 1          |        5    |     00:57    |
| 2          |        6    |     00:10    |
| 2          |        6    |     00:20    |
```

Should result in this:

```
| user_id    | track_id    | created_at   |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |        5    |     00:00    |
| 1          |        5    |     00:57    |
| 2          |        6    |     00:10    |
```

Rows 1-3 are merged because they are inside of a 30min window, same user, same track_id. Row 4 is outside of the 30 min window, so it remains a seperate row.
Rows 5-6 are merged.

Is it possible to solve this by a query or should i put some application logic around this?

Comment: What if you have times like 00:00, 00:10, 00:20, 00:30, 00:40?  Is that one group or two?  If two, what are they?

Comment: These would be two groups. The start of the window is defined by the time of the first entry. So in this case it would be group 1 ( 00:00, 00:10, 00:20, 00:30 ) and group 2 (00:40)